# TypeError: $.equals is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, backend

I'm using ExpressJS and I have a problem where the `.equals()` method is not recognized. The two objects are of different types, but both have the same value. I modified the operator to `==`, but it continuously jumps to the else statement.

I want to know **'how'** I can compare these two parameters and how I can correct the error in the `if` statement with the objective being that I ensure that a user can edit a profile `if` they are the owner.

Here is my code along with the output and the database. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

======================    **Problem SOLVED**

the code:.............................................................

```
app.use("/teachers/:id/editProfile", function (req, res ){

    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        Teacher.findById(req.params.id, function(err , foundTeacher){
            if(err){
                res.redirect("/teachers");
            }else{

                    console.log("WHAT !    " + foundTeacher._id );
                    console.log("WHAT !    " + req.user.profile );

                    if(req.user.profile.equals(foundTeacher._id) ){
                        res.send("YOU HAVE PERM ............");

                    }else{
                        res.send("YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO DO THAT");
                    }
            }
        })
    }else{
        res.send("YOU NEED TO BE LOGGED IN TO DO THAT");
    }
```

the output:.................................................................

```
WHAT !    5c8b73b2e9b9ec2179224ef4
WHAT !    5c8b73b2e9b9ec2179224ef4
```

events.js:160

```
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: req.user.profile.equals is not a function
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/LearnFaceToFace/app.js:211:41
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/LearnFaceToFace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4719:16
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/LearnFaceToFace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4099:12
at process.nextTick (/home/ubuntu/workspace/LearnFaceToFace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2681:28)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

mongoose DB:................................................................

> db.teachers.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8b73b2e9b9ec2179224ef4"), "name" : "mr.s", "teachingField" : "math", "price" : "111$", "contact" : "ddd@gmail.com", "note" : "best page", "sex" : "male", "image" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSx2puLa7PoZiDMIAGChIP73M6NhfchM6A8ia_ZQXwmGP6IdtlnAw", "__v" : 0 }
```

> db.users.find()

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8b73a6e9b9ec2179224ef3"), "profile" : [ ObjectId("5c8b73b2e9b9ec2179224ef4") ], "username" : "s1", "salt" : "e1c55598efe775b66bbf95ed7978e8ec410d8d2983823336eb6f59ac28ddfb6c", "hash" : "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", "__v" : 1 }
```

the user Schema ....................................................

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    username: String,

    password: String,

    profile:[

        {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

        ref: "profile"

        }]

});
```

Comment: maybe some of your users have profiles, and some don't? - check if it exists before using it - although you'd also need to decide what to do if a user doesn't have a profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, first things first. When something goes wrong, and you decide to debug it with console.log, NEVER use `+`. Yes, I know it's beneficial to get some label on that data, but here's the trick: this...

```
console.log('SOME_LABEL:', some_data);
```

... will give you more-o-less detailed info about this data. And this...

```
console.log('SOME_LABEL:' + some_data);
```

... will *always* show you a string - result of concatenation of SOME_LABEL string and some_data **cast** to string. And yes, in JS something cast to string is not the same as representation of this something.

In fact, that's exactly the problem here. Both checked values are not strings - they are objects(*). And unless you have the same object on both side of `==` or `===`, you should always expect to get `false` from that operation. Again, that's the case here.

Yes, there are utility methods on some libraries ([_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual)) that allow you to compare objects by value, but those methods are called essentially as standalone functions and do not become available on all objects automatically. And there's a reason for that.

Usually when you do need to compare two objects of same type (class), you better either implement some comparison method on them or compare them cast to primitives. Otherwise you'll end up checking again and again both useful properties and something that's not really needed to be compared.

In this particular case, there's a property on `ObjectId` just for that comparison purpose - [str](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#methods-and-attributes):

> `str`
>
> Returns the hexadecimal string representation of the object.

So one possible approach to make the check is this:

```
if (req.user.profile.str === foundTeacher._id.str) { ... }
```

**Ok, `foundTeacher._id` is ObjectId, but you'd better double-check what `req.user.profile` actually is. If it's a string, just drop that `str` property check.*

Comment: first, i changed my checking method console.log from + to " , " and it really helped the new result:

WHAT ! 5c8b73b2e9b9ec2179224ef4

WHAT ! ["5c8b73b2e9b9ec2179224ef4"]

second,great clarification, i really didn't think the type would effect that much, especially when my old "bad" checking method was returning the same value, it drove me crazy. at last,your solution worked perfectly,i discovered a new solution.

if(req.user.profile[0].equals(foundTeacher._id) ){....}

i specified the index of the object and it worked also. i want to thank you again for your help @raina77ow

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, if you found that answer helpful, you can accept it so the question can be considered closed. )

Answer (score 0):

You should actually try doing it the other way around.

```
foundTeacher._id.equals(req.user.profile)
```

"===" or "==" operators won't work in this case as one of the ids is a String and other one is mongodb objectid so you have to use the method provided by mongoose to compare these to values.

Comment: i tried it, unfortunately it didn't work. i had to either to specify the index like req.user.profile[0] and the .equals method will work, or using the === and add .str like Mr.raina77ow said.
thank you for your help